# Google Scripts Custom Function - Array of Ranges as a Parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, scripting, google-sheets

I am relatively new to creating custom functions in Google Scripts.

I need to be able to pass in an array of ranges into a function.

Please let me know if I am approaching this incorrectly.

I am getting a parse error when I reference it in Google Sheets as `=ConcatEach(["A1:A2","B1:B2"],"$"])` (Without the quotes.)

(Also, the values are arbitrary. I know dollar signs go before the value.)

Anyway, here is what I have:

```
 function ConcatEach(rangeString, concatString)
 {
  //var rangeString = ["A1:A2","B1:B2"];
  //var concatString = "$";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rangeValues=[];
  for(i=0;i<rangeString.length;i++)
  {
    var range = sheet.getRange(rangeString[i]);
    rangeValues.push(range.getValues());
  }

  //Logger.log(rangeValues);

  for(i=0;i<rangeValues.length;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<rangeValues[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(rangeValues[i][j] != "")
      {
        rangeValues[i][j] = rangeValues[i][j] + concatString;
      }
    }
  }
  return rangeValues;
}
```

Any help would be super appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may pass `rangeString` as string with commas:

```
"A1:A2,B1:B2"
```

and then use [JavaScript String split() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp):

```
var array =  rangeString.split(",");
Logger.log(array); // you'll get array ['A1:A2', 'B1:B2']
```